# Jenkins run another job on quiet mode

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, devops, jenkins-groovy

I have a Jenkinsfile that calls another job. It looks something like this: (Other than that there's onlt the `pipeline` wrapper with `agent any`.

```
stage('Call Job1') {
            steps{
            build job: 'Job1', parameters: [
                    [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'gitBranch', value: "${gitBranch}"],
                    [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'callingJob', value: "${JOB_NAME}"]
                ]
        }
}
```

But for some reason, it runs the job on really long quiet mode, even though it's not defined anywhere:

```
(pending—In the quiet period. Expires in 9 hr 40 min)
```

When I go to said job and put in the same parameters manually, it works right away.

Am I doing something wrong? I couldn't find anything online

Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: called the job like this:

```
build job: 'Job1', quietPeriod: 0,parameters
```

though I feel like there should be a better solution.